# Why do some scientific possessives have trailing "s" and others don't?

Tags: terminology, english, grammar

I debated names of scientific terms with my friend, and we both discovered that some of them have the trailing letter "s" while others don't.
Here are some examples:

- Mobius strip, Fourier series, Chomsky normal form — you can see there are no "s" letters in the end of the names
- Fermat**'s** last theorem, Occam**'s** razor, Godel**'s** incompleteness — while they are present here

How could this ambiguity be resolved? What could be its reason or is it just random?

Comment: When someone hypothesizes a theorem, it is considered his/hers and it is appropriate to use the possesive, so you have Fermat's (last) theorem, Godel's (incompleteness) theorem etc. Whereas a term like "Chomsky normal form", Chomsky did not create the form, he's merely responsible for labeling it and distinguishing it from other forms. The same would be true for Fourier series and Mobius strip.

Comment: I think this is the answer. *Gödel's incompleteness* seems wrong to me for exactly that reason, while *Gödel's incompleteness theorem* is correct. Even though, strictly speaking, theorems are found rather than created.

Answer (score 2):

The first type, without 's, are nouns (N for short).  The second type are noun phrases (NP for short).  This is made less obvious by a spelling convention which tries to distinguish words from phrases by whether they are written with internal spaces.  A noun phrase is a major constituent of sentences, subject or object, and prepositional phrases.  A noun is an important constituent of most noun phrases.  In many cases, noun phrases are introduced by an article or other determiner, while nouns cannot contain articles.

The first two nouns in the examples are compound nouns.  Compound nouns are made up of several words (usually nouns).  In modern English, the individual parts of compounds cannot be inflected, and that is why you find no 's.  There are a few archaic compounds that do have internal inflectional endings, like "sargeants-at-arms".  Many English compounds have more stress on the first element of the compound, and the first two examples are like this.

I'm not sure about the example "Chomsky normal form".  It's not much like the first two examples.  Would "Chomsky's normal form" also sound okay in some contexts?

Notice that you can add an article to the noun compounds to form a noun phrase, just as expected for nouns -- "a Moebius strip".  In the second examples with 's, the noun phrases, the initial word with 's is a determiner -- it is a possessive form that has a similar grammatical function to "the".  A noun phrase can have only one determiner, so you wouldn't expect to see an article added to these (although it may be an accident of the examples that the referents are unique).

Comment: _Chomsky Normal Form_ seems like Backus Normal Form (BNF), which is now called Backus-Naur Form, thus preserving the TLF _BNF_. But I don't think academics in every discipline follow the same nomenclature. My favorite example is Leonhard Euler; if credit were apportioned where it belonged, most mathematical phenomena would have _Euler('s)_ in their name. For instance, [Euler's Formula](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/EulersFormula.pdf), which refers to Taylor Series (not "Taylor's Series").

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided examples, I would distinguish as follows:

When a scholar points out some recurring abstract phenomenon and gives it a name, we refer to an instance of this abstraction as `a {scholar} {label}`. Whereas, when the scholar introduces some tool of reasoning such as a theorem, we refer to the tool using the possessive: `{scholar}'s {tool}`.

So practically to determine which form is appropriate test whether the term, `x`, can fit into an `a x` phrase, if it can, use the noun adjunct; otherwise, use the possessive.

Answer (score 0):

Aforementioned friend chiming in: I have discovered that the former row of examples is based on a construction known as [noun adjunct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct), while the latter most likely employs possessive nouns.

I still don't have the slightest idea when to use which, though, and how one would construct those terms in the first place.

Comment: I looked at your reference for "noun adjunct", and since the Wikipedia article calls the combination of one of these noun adjuncts with a following noun a compound noun, this is not different from what I said (after you said it).  I wasn't familiar with the term "noun adjunct", and I don't really like it.  Why have a special term for the first parts of compound nouns when the semantic function is "modification"?  Those compounds work the same way as other compounds, so far as I know.